# the function print in python displays me nothing

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a problem with my function in python

I have a list of 10 names, and I want compare the distance with the names 1 and the name 2 and with the name 1 with the name 3 ....10   and after the name 2 with the name 3 .....  into 10 ...

I create a functiond dist_date, who gives the distance between the 2 dates of the authors.

For example  `print(dist_date('Veryan Heal','Brian G. Field'))` gives `0.25`

But when I try do it with a loop like it :

```
valeur = []
valeur2 = []
for x in range(len(names)):
    for i in range(x + 1, len(names)):
        if dist_name(names[x],names[i]) < 0.3 and dist_name(names[x],names[i])!=None:
            print(dist_date('names[x]','names[y]'))
```

It doesn't work but the most strange is that I see  that my python is exec my code but nothing appears.   It's like if I had only white value ,  a white pagina.

Thanks for reading me

Comment: What nothing change ? Did it print something ? do `print(names[x], names[i], dist_name(names[x],names[i]) )`

Comment: Are the list empty ? Please make do some effort, print the value after each for loop to see what item you're going to use

Comment: The print won't happen at all when the `if` condition is false.

Comment: your code shows `valeur` and `valeur2` which seem to be unused. your code also shows `names` which we can't see the definition of.

Comment: I have names and dates,  but when I say  ``` print(dist_date('names[x]','names[i]')) ```     python print me just white pagina and exec my code for nothing

Comment: You have quotes around names[], so it passes a string, not the value from the array. Also your function may ALWAYS return something, like -1 or None if the input if not correct, coul you share the function ?

Answer (score -1):

Add lots more print statements so you can see exactly what the program is doing.  Print a message at the top of every loop and the top of every if/else branch:

```
for x in range(len(names)):
    print("Looping x=%d" % x)
    for i in range(x + 1, len(names)):
        print("Looping i=%d" % i)
        if dist_name(names[x],names[i]) < 0.3 and dist_name(names[x],names[i])!=None:
            print("If condition was true")
            print(dist_date(names[x],names[y]))
        else:
            print("If condition was false")
```

Comment: The purpose of SO is not to help people debugging their code, here the OP doesn't give enough detail so no answer can be given as the problem is not given

Comment: @MattClark debug in comment not an answer that tells you 'use prints' and see

Comment: If I could have put this in a comment, I would have.  But comments do not allow for detailed code such as this.